# Bash script to find files from a directory and move them to different location

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file named files.csv, and contains directory name(column A) and file names(Column B)

[image]

---

Currently the files(file1,file2..) are available in the linux machine in a different directory and would need to move them as per the details provided in files.csv file.
I humbly request suggestions on bash script, that can help me first find the files mentioned in the csv file and further move them according to the directory name provided.

Comment: The command to find files is: [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Do you know where the original files are, or you have no clue?.

Comment: Im aware of the original file's folder, for instance here it is /home/admin/main/

Comment: Where is for example `dir1` located? `/home/admin/main/dir1`?

Comment: its in /home/admin/Documents/

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a `bash` script.

The following is a programmatic solution approach. Not tested!!!

**Be very careful before executing `mv` command as it maybe destructive.**

```
#!/bin/bash

#create a find command to locate all files in single command:
findCommand=$(awk -F, '{filesArr[++c]=$2;}END{
  cmd = "find / -type f ";
  seperator = "";
  for (i in filesArr) {
    cmd = sprintf("%s %s -name \"%s\"", cmd, seperator, $2);
    seperator = "-or"
  }
  cmd = cmd " 2>/dev/null";
  print cmd;
}' input.csv)

#print findCommand
echo "$findCommand"

# collect all file names in filesList (can take long time to execute)
# assuming filename are unique and not contain `&` in filenames
readarray -t filesList <<< $("$findCommand")

# for each found file
for file in ${filesList[@]}; do
   echo "$file"
   #append found file to csv list to match its basename
   currFilename=$(basename "$file")
   sed -i 's|,'"$currFilename"'$|,'"$currFilename","$file"'|' input.csv
done
# if files are located in 2 or more place, the csv will append first location only
# if file is not located its 3rd column will stay empty

# build a mv commands for each file with location using awk
awk -F, 'NF>2{cmd=" mv \""$3"\" \""$1"\"";print cmd}' input.csv

# when ready to run the mv commands uncomment the following line
# awk -F, 'NF>2{cmd=" mv \""$3"\" \""$1"\"";system(cmd)}' input.csv
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion.. have helped me with the accomplishing the task

Comment: please mark question as answered.